# How can you make the title of the Econometrica journal?

Tags: titles

I'm trying to make a template for Econometrica magazine but I don't know what type of font it uses and also how the Econometrica title can be made the same size.

[image: Revista Econometrica]

Is there any availability to generate your bibliographic citations in Econometrica style?

Comment: If you want to publish there, look for LaTeX templates for authors. You won't need to (re)create their title page, in any case.

Comment: The font is just Times or a Times clone, isn't it? `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`. As for the font size, there are other questions on this site about how to set a specific font size.

Answer (score 0):

[if this is experimental rather than practical:] I would suggest https://ctan.org/pkg/econometrica?lang=en, https://www.e-publications.org/ecta/support/#ectaart, as a start to figuring it out. Comment if your still stuck on this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!